# Procedure in PL/SQL with create and cursor

Tags: database, plsql, procedure, procedural-programming

Can we have a Procedure with

First create a table suppose

```
  create table INCOME_GROUP(income_compare_groups varchar(100)) ;
```

Then insert data into this table.

```
 insert into INCOME_GROUP values (10-20);
```

Then Use this table into a cursor.

```
 CURSOR c1 IS(select *from INCOME_GROUP);
```

For Example I am doing this.

```
BEGIN 
create table INCOME_GROUP(income_compare_groups varchar(100)) ;
DECLARE

   CURSOR c1 IS(select * income_Group);
BEGIN
   FOR acct IN c1 LOOP  -- process each row one at a time

      INSERT INTO temp_test
            VALUES (acct.income_compare_groups);


   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
END;
```

But I am getting some Error.

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

After reading the comments I tried this -

```
BEGIN 
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table INCOME_GROUP
 (
  income_compare_groups varchar(100)
  )'; 
DECLARE

   CURSOR c1 IS
     (select * from
       INCOME_GROUP
    );



BEGIN

 FOR acct IN c1 LOOP  -- process each row one at a time



      INSERT INTO temp_test
            VALUES (acct.income_compare_groups, null);


   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
END;
```

But seems it is not creating table.!!!!

Comment: You cannot run DDL statements (`create`) in a procedure directly. You need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Update question with errors you are getting.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you please elaborate how to use dynamic sql because i am new for procedure programming.

Comment: @Bishan Done with the required!!!

Comment: See the manual for details on how to use dynamic SQL: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011

Answer (score 1):

It must be like this:

```
DECLARE
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
     v_income_compare_groups VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE INCOME_GROUP(income_compare_groups VARCHAR(100))';
    OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT * income_Group';
    LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO v_income_compare_groups;
        EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
        INSERT INTO temp_test VALUES (v_income_compare_groups);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

You have to use dynamic Cursor because when you compile the package then the table INCOME_GROUP does not exist yet and you would get an error at `CURSOR c1 IS(select * income_Group);`

However, there are several issue:
You will get an error if the table already exist. You have to check this first or write an exception handler.
The procedure is useless because you first create an (empty) table and then you select it - it will never select anything!

Comment: can we insert data also using execute immediate

Comment: If suppose i have table INCOME_GROUP with multiple column then how to iterate it.

Comment: You can put almost everything into `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''`, include insert statements with several columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
create or replace procedure cpy_inc_comp_grps
as
cur_1 sys_refcursor;
compare_group varchar2(100);
begin
  execute immediate 'create table income_group(income_compare_groups varchar2(100))';
  open cur_1 for 'select income_compare_groups from income_group';

  LOOP
  FETCH cur_1 INTO compare_group;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERT INTO temp_test VALUES (rec.income_compare_groups');
  EXIT WHEN cur_1%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  close cur_1;
  execute immediate 'drop table income_group';
end;
```

And test it with the following code:

```
begin
  cpy_inc_comp_grps;
end;
```

You have to replace the `dbms_output.put_line(...)` part with whatever inserts you want to do.

Comment: If suppose i have table INCOME_GROUP with multiple column then how to iterate it.

Comment: `FETCH cur_1 INTO compare_group, var_for_COLUMN2, var_for_COLUMN3, ...`

Comment: And if you want to insert Data, just use the normal SQL statement `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, ...)`. You don't need `execute immediate` for the `INSERT`-statement

Comment: one more thing why this procedure is taking lot of time to execute!!

Comment: I don't know, it's executing pretty fast for me. Do you mean this example or your final statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
execute immediate 'create table INCOME_GROUP(income_compare_groups varchar(100))';
```